# pg_config executable not found when using pgxnclient on Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, postgresql-9.3

I installed Python 2.7.8 and pgxn client. And I tried to run this statement from command line from the bin folder and path is setup correctly

```
pgxnclient install  http://api.pgxn.org/dist/pg_repack/1.2.1/pg_repack-1.2.1.zip
```

But I got an error `pg_config executable not found`.

Comment: I have no idea if pgxn supports Windows at all. Given that PGXS (the compilation system for extensions) doesn't support Windows, I rather doubt it can work for any extension that requires C compilation.

Comment: Mladen, what operating system are you trying this on? You will need pg_config available, as well as the PostgreSQL headers installed (if installing on Linux from a packaging system, there is usually a -dev package needed). In case you are trying this on Windows, pg_repack is basically untested/unsupported on Windows.

Comment: I am using the Win 7 x64 bit as stated in the question. I am just exploring the PostgreSQL. It seems that the best way to use it is on linux. There is a project inside the zip file for 2010, but I need to adapt it for PostgreSQL 9.3 which I am using. It will wait for some time.

Comment: @Mladen I would be interested if you successfully compiled it for PG 9.3 under Visual 2010.

Comment: I didn't and currently I am not planning to. I tried PostgreSQL on linux and it's much more performant and easier to use. In future I'll be using more Linux and software running on it. ;) PS. I had a lot of hassle to configure Visual studio for compiling 64 bit, I recommend to use VS 2012 immediately.

Comment: I succeded to compile and install the extension on Linux today.

Answer (score 33):

Bakground:  pg_config is the configuration utility provided by **PostgreSQL**.  This utility is used by various applications.

**Solution:**

1. Install [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).
2. Set the path.  System Properties > Advanced

   PATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\;

From this point on, any application that requires pg_config can find it here.

I suggest this method because the build is directly from the author.  You can also find viable alternatives for standalone pg_config builds.

Comment: Thank your for your time and effort. It was configured as you said. But I had problems with running pgxn client. I solved the problem by using linux and running it there. PostgreSQL is OK on windows but rocks on linux. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error, and `pg_config` was in my path

You can try

`pgxnclient install --pg_config "c:\path\to\pg_config.exe" $extensionName`

You almost definitely need to run `cmd.exe` as an admin

Comment: this worked, thanks. But then I got an error for gmake being unavailable. I think pgxnclient is only meant to run on linux... "Windows binary versions auto-built upon submission" is in the wishlist on https://github.com/pgxn/pgxn/wiki/PGXN-Wish-List

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax

```
pgxnclient install --pg_config 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_config.exe' quantile
```

Comment: Isn't this really just the same guidance as [@Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424294/3025856) from six years ago? Except with a concrete path and extension, whereas Neil kept their answer general?

Comment: When you say "correct syntax", are you saying there was a mistake in the previous answer? You use different quotes, is that significant? Please be explicit as to what change you are recommending.

Comment: It should be complete either.