# pg_config executable not found on Windows 7 with PostgreSQL installed

Tags: python, django, git, postgresql, heroku

I'm following the Heroku guide on using Python with Heroku.

I'm on the step for [installing dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies), but when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external`, I get this error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --pg-config C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_config.exe` from the Django app's root directory via Git, I get a `no such directory` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Once try this `pip install -r requirements.txt` by activating your virtualenv

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717436/pg-config-executable-not-found-when-using-pgxnclient-on-windows-7-x64/28069597#28069597    try this answer