# Error when installing psycopg2 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, psycopg2

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  running egg_info
  creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
  writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\peppe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-599lt1cp\psycopg2\
```

Every time I attempt to run `pip install psycopg2` I get the above error. I tried to download the compiled version, but when I run it, I get an error telling me Python 3.5 must be installed. I have Python 3.5 x86 installed, and I downloaded the x86 version of psycopg2 to match it, so I really cannot find a solution. Anyone have any ideas? I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the error? Added the folder with pg_config to the PATH?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717436/pg-config-executable-not-found-when-using-pgxnclient-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have no idea where the pg_config is

Comment: It's probably in the bin folder of your postgresql installation.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I just realized I didn't install it. Figuring it out now

Comment: Try `psycopg2-2.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

Answer (score 3):

Installed *psycopg2* on Windows 10 without issues:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Ensure you have the PostgreSQL executables incl. DLL's in your PATH:

```
%PG_HOME%\bin;%PG_HOME%\lib
```

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted w/o comment. It does actually work. Make sure you close all CMD or powershell and pycharm if using it and restart them.

Comment: Successfully installed psycopg2 using `pip install psycopg2` on Windows 10

Comment: Yep, but you need to install postgres server on your own machine. Usually it is not necessary

Answer (score -1):

Just install C++ build tools

- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
- And then, `pip install psycopg2`. and you should see:

  Successfully built psycopg2

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: @zixuan It is a dependency. You need to install all c++ build tools that accomodates psycopg2 in windows. In Ubuntu flavors, you can install these libraries with 'sudo apt-get install build-essential'