# How to install psycopg2 on windows 10?

Tags: python

While trying to install psycopg2-binary with pip3, I get the following error message:

> Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

I have 83  error LNK2001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, I could not install psycopg2. When browsing around, people were saying to isntall directly the binary which I was trying to do. However for some reasons, the 64 bits binary was not working but the 32 bits version has worked fine and solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you installing `psycopg2-binary` and not just `psycopg2`? Also make sure you have PostgreSQL executables and DLLs in PATH as advised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525663/9957798) answer.